# Cos'è il "granoturco soffiato" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Ai piedi delle montagne russe, mentre i vagoncini vuoti arrancavano sferragliando verso l’apice della salita, si frugò la tasca interna della giacca per accertarsi di poter comprare a Vita una domenica di gioia – nonostante tutto, contro tutto. Fra i baracconi, gli ambulanti vendevano granoturco abbrustolito, frittelle, noccioline, gelati, zucchero filato che una vecchia tutta gengive avvolgeva attorno a un bastoncino. Il **granoturco soffiato** sembrava un mare di nuvole, ma quando affondò la bocca, gli scrocchiò sotto i denti. Il popcorn aveva un sapore di gomma e di sale, s’attaccava alla lingua. Si chiese se fosse quello, il sapore della saliva di Vita.

La mia domanda è sul significato dell'espressione "granoturco soffiato" che appare in questo passaggio. Nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/corn-flakes/) ho visto che può riferirsi ai cosiddetti "corn flakes". Tuttavia, questo non sembra avere molto senso nel contesto del brano. Sarebbe lo stesso che "il popcorn" di cui parla la frase successiva?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il [Sabatini Coletti](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/soffiato.shtml)  dà la definizione di

***riso soffiato:***

> - riso soffice, fatto gonfiare con il calore in un contenitore chiuso.

La stessa procedura viene usata con altri cereali per ottenere l’”effetto soffiato”.

Nel caso del granoturco, quello soffiato e più comunemente conosciuto come “popcorn”.